# Possible to Convert and Display Weight Value in both Kilograms and Pounds and Ounces?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to be able to give a user the option to enter a weight value in pounds and ounces and have it display both the entered pounds and ounces and the weight converted to kilograms, or enter the weight in kilograms and have it display both the kilogram value and also in pounds and ounces.

I currently have a sheet configured for a user to enter pounds in one cell and ounces in a second cell. A formula converts the pounds to ounces and adds it to the ounces if any were entered in the ounce cell. Another formula then converts the value of the total ounces to kilograms. I would like the user to also have the option to also start with kilograms and have that value converted and display as pounds and ounces. However my kilogram cell already has a formula on it to convert total ounces to kilograms, so it will not accept data.

Here is an example of the sheet as currently configured.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IHknfTNo2A_Nhxn8MDuco8q-GnD2UnYu8chtO4ABjH4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Use three entry columns — pounds, ounces, kilograms — and two formula columns like this:

```
=ifs( 
  (E2 + F2) * G2, 
    "enter lb+oz, or kg, not both", 
  E2 + F2, 
    sum( convert(E2, "lbm", "ozm"), F2 ), 
  G2, 
    convert(G2, "kg", "ozm"), 
  true, 
    iferror(1/0) 
)
```

```
=ifs( 
  (E2 + F2) * G2, 
    "enter lb+oz, or kg, not both", 
  E2 + F2, 
    convert(H2, "ozm", "kg"), 
  G2, 
    G2, 
  true, 
    iferror(1/0) 
)
```

The formula columns let you see the result in both ounces and kilograms for every entry.

See the new [Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IHknfTNo2A_Nhxn8MDuco8q-GnD2UnYu8chtO4ABjH4/edit#gid=485763294) sheet in your sample spreadsheet.